# Matlab: UTF-8 to bitstring representation

Tags: matlab, file-io, utf-8, binary

I have a file that contains a 16 character long sequence of UTF-8 which I want to read out
and then convert to a 128 bitstring. The file is read out in the following way:

```
fid      = fopen('file_0','r','n','UTF-8')
utf8_val = fgetl(fid);
```

Anyone now an an idea how I can convert the utf8_val into a 128 bitstring representation?
Hope Matlab provides some function for that :).

Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems like an odd thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not read from the file directly as bytes

```
%# read bytes
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'rb');
b = fread(fid, '*uint8')';
fclose(fid);
```

Then if you wish you could convert it to a UTF-8 string

```
%# convert to Unicode string
s = native2unicode(b, 'UTF-8');
```